# Why is android studio instantiating tests each time?

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-studio, robolectric

When I try to run unit tests in android studio, I can see it make, build gradle, etc... all the build stuff, and then I can see an instantiating tests ... which counts up to 9 every time, even if I don't change anything.

 
In total, running a single test, even without robolectric takes about 30 seconds. 

Is there a cache option that I can set on android studio so it doesn't do this?


The reason I'm asking is because sometimes this doesn't happen. Sometimes when I run the tests I just get about 5 seconds of waiting and the tests start with no instantiating or anything, even if I do change stuff, in the tests or otherwise. This works like this then for the full session. After I restart my computer it goes back to normal.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking, what do you mean by instantiating tests? Are you trying to speed up the build or running the tests?

Comment: So when I run the tests the app starts to build(make, gradle build, etc.), after the build finishes, the tests start initiating. This is a state in the test view where you can see the text "initiating tests..." that takes about 9 seconds. When I run all the tests this is not a big problem, but when i try to  run individual tests because I'm working on them it's very annoying. As I said in the initial question, I only consider there is a better way since it doesn't always do this.

Comment: Got it. I'm not sure there is a solution. Robolectric tries to cache as much as possible, so that's why sometimes the startup time is faster. But it's not always possible and I think especially loading the resources is slow. You could try to enable running tests in parallel, but obviously that won't help with the startup time issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what worked for me in the end.

If you go to Run/Debug Configurations and delete all the previous configurations, the tests start a lot faster. Also, doing this helps when you change between Unit tests and Instrumentation tests and you get the "ResultPrinter" error.